# Wrong URL redirecting to search engines for all browsers (yahoo in my case)

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser, redirection, search-engines

I am getting a strange error first time. Whenever I enter a wrong URL/domain, it redirect me to following link:-

> http://in.yhs4.search.yahoo.com/yhs/errorhandler?hsimp=yhse-001&hspart=CND&type=A0196687591F04C1AACF_s_g_e&q=http://localhost:3000/wrongurl

I searched over internet but did not find any positive solution.

I have tried following for firefox browser:-

1. Reset Firefox in safe and without safe mode
2. change about:config >> keyword.enabled (not found keyword.URL in my system as everywhere mentioned)
3. change internet options of windows like default search etc
4. Virus scanned with MS Essential updated version

I also restarted firefox and system but still getting the error. Because of this error, I am unable to see errors while web-development and gone to log file again and again.

Please find the solution if anyone faced this problem ever.

Thanks.

Comment: What DNS servers are you using?

Comment: I am connected with LAN with DNS address 192.168.1.1

Comment: Yeah, we need to know what dns your router uses

Comment: It is connected to airtel.in.
DNS Description : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
If this is not what you asking, please clear how can I get the dns router.
Thanks

Comment: does sound like your DNS server what internet service provider are you using?

Comment: No, this is not ISP related issue. I am not getting this issue on other system connected with same ISP. I think this might be some malwares related installed automatically while installing other S/W.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem.
This is because of **conduit search** that was automatically installed in my system while installing a software.
Initially I was failing because of removing all services names with **yahoo** as I was redirecting to `http://in.yhs4.search.yahoo.com`. But in actual, this yahoo search was internally associated with conduit search.

Then I tried to remove **conduit search** service, it automatically removed redirection to yahoo search.

Now I can get errors on my developed web pages if they are (with redirection).

@Paul/@Rob : Thanks for your help.