# Getting redirected to us.yhs4.search.yahoo.com/yhs/errorhandler : How to change that?

Tags: networking, dns, redirection

If there is an error in an URL or the network is down my browser is always redirected to `us.yhs4.search.yahoo.com/yhs/errorhandler` (possibly with a longer URL, but that is the base).

I used to get a 404 error page or something from the server I've contacted but this appears to have replaced it.  How can I change my browser, windows settings or other to go back to default behavior and what is causing this redirection to Yahoo?

It's important to me not only for web use and development but also I don't want the feeling that in this way Yahoo is tracking my browser errors.

I saw another similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/739995/wrong-url-redirecting-to-search-engines-for-all-browsers-yahoo-in-my-case) where the solution was to remove a service called 'Conduit' but I do not see that in my list of services.

My DNS servers are,

```
205.152.37.23
8.8.8.8
198.6.1.5
68.94.156.1
<...>
```

then the router:

```
192.168.1.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a number of things...  you could have picked up Malware or installed an extension that is doing this to you.

It's also possible one of the DNS servers is doing this now with an NXDOMAIN redirect.  A probe of 205.152.37.23 (Bell South), 198.6.1.5 (MCI) and 8.8.8.8 (Google) for a non-existent names gives an NXDOMAIN response, so it's not one of those.  But the AT&T one is suspect (68.94.156.1) and could be doing it, I can't probe it (blocked).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I would look for an NXDOMAIN redirection by probing -- what tool could I use for this?  Also, I have a list of DNS servers entered in the network setup section (Windows 7) to improve the (poor) performance of the AT&T default DNS through our router's setup.  I used tools such as DNS Bench and NameBench to help find better choices for the top of the list -- presumably that is the search order (from top to bottom)? This seems only to happen using Firefox web browser -- would that browser perhaps be susceptible where another (Chrome) is not?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: `nslookup` from command-line works on Windows (built-in).  And I understand adding more IPs to your list of nameservers to use, but that list is not ordered in Win7 (and later).  They are treated as equivalent and the order used is randomized every 15 minutes.  And if this only happens with Firefox, then Malware probably is your root cause.